# Why mask done't work on UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, calayer, uisearchbar

I am trying to add round corner to UISearchBar at the top-left and top-right corners.

However, I found the mask layer doesn't work on UISearchBar, no matter how I set it.

Here is my code

```
    // UIView* bar = [searchBar_.subviews objectAtIndex:0]; // try to add mask to background view but also failed

    UIView* bar = searchBar_;
    CGRect toolbarBounds = bar.bounds;
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: toolbarBounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft 
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f)];
    [maskLayer setPath:[path CGPath]];
    [maskLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];
    bar.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    bar.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

I have also tried the "Clip subviews", but it doesn't work either.

Then I try something more, I just set the background view (subview 0) hidden.  To mu surprise, it is still visible.

Is there any magic in the UISearchBar?
The mask does work on UIToolbar.

Comment: Have you tried `view.layer.cornerRadius`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be related to how the `mask` property is implemented. It will not work if you add a mask layer to a layer which is already part of a hierarchy. The docs for `CALayer` say:

> When setting the `mask` to a new layer, the new layer’s superlayer must first be set to `nil`, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

You'll have to remove the search bar from its `superview` before adding the mask layer. Wrap your last line like so:

```
UIView *superview = [bar superview];
[bar removeFromSuperview];
bar.layer.mask = maskLayer;
[superview addSubview:bar];
```

You can also use `removeFromSuperlayer` and `addSublayer:` if you prefer. Also, if your search bar isn't the topmost view in your hierarchy, make sure to find out where it is and put it back in the right place using `insertSubview:atIndex:` or one of the similar methods.